# React - call consecutive fetch operations (mtutally dependent)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to call 2 fetch operations where second fetch requires id returned from first call?

My code:

```
useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const aaa=
                await service.getDefaultTemplate();

            const bbb=
                await service.getAnnouncementTemplate({
                    templateId: aaa.id,
                });
            setAaa(aaa); //useState
            setBbb(bbb); //useState
        };
        fetchData().catch(noop)
    }, []);
```

Only first result aaa is returned, bbb is null

UPDATE

after first answer:

```
 useEffect(() => {
 service
            .getDefaultAnnouncementTemplate()
            .then((aaa) => {
                setAAA(aaa);
                service
                    .getAnnouncementTemplate({
                        templateId: aaa.id,
                    })
                    .then((bbb) => {
                        setBbb(bbb);
                    })
                    .catch(noop);
            })
            .catch(noop);
}, []);
```

BUt I get warning: Eslint: avoid nesting promises

Comment: Have you confirmed that both `aaa` and `bbb` actually get values before the `set` calls?

Comment: That eslint warning is only a problem if you intend to let a dumb robot tell you how to write programs. You could _not_ do that.

Comment: Tip: if you `return` the inner service call, you don't need to declare the inner `.catch`.

Comment: "Only first result aaa is returned, bbb is null" I don't think it is an `async/await` issue. because if it were, then your code would crash when you call `await service.getAnnouncementTemplate({ templateId: aaa.id });`, since `aaa` would be undefined. Also, if `bbb` is null, it means that's what your function call returned with the given input.

Comment: @Tom Nested promises here make little sense and make the code harder to reason about. The dumb robot is making the suggestion for a reason.

Answer (score 3):

to avoid nesting promises warning:

```js
useEffect(() => {
 service.getDefaultAnnouncementTemplate()
 .then((aaa) => {
   setAAA(aaa);
   return service.getAnnouncementTemplate({templateId: aaa.id})
 })
 .then((bbb) => setBbb(bbb))
 .catch(noop);
}, []);
```

But your snippet with async/await looks good. Check input and output of *service.getAnnouncementTemplate* method

Answer (score 0):

you can make them dependent with a return, inside the first call you can return any status, maybe an object or something so the code will look like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const aaa=
                await service.getDefaultTemplate();
            if(aaa.status !== "success") return;
            const bbb=
                await service.getAnnouncementTemplate({
                    templateId: aaa.id,
                });
            setAaa(aaa); //useState
            setBbb(bbb); //useState
        };
        fetchData().catch(noop)
    }, []);
```

that way if the first call is not a success you kill the execution, what you need to do and the vital part is to return any value from the fetch that will tell you its a success or an error